# SYMFONY2: SQL to CreateQueryBuilder or CreateQuery

Tags: sql, symfony, query-builder

can someone help me convert this sql to symfony?

```
SELECT cl.* from computador_coleta cl inner join class_property p on cl.id_class_property = p.id_class_property where p.id_class = 15 AND cl.id_computador = 2510;
```

cl.id_computador is a variable.

Answer (score 3):

```
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $query = $em->createQuery(
            'SELECT cc FROM CacicCommonBundle:ComputadorColeta cc INNER JOIN CacicCommonBundle:ClassProperty cp WITH cc.classProperty = cp.idClassProperty WHERE cp.idClass = 15 AND cc.computador = :id'
        )->setParameter('id', $computador);

        $result = $query->getResult();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
 $qb = $em->createQueryBuilder();

 $result = $qb->select('c')
             ->from('CacicCommonBundle:ComputadorColeta','cc')
             ->innerJoin('cc.classProperty','cp')
             ->where('cp.idClass = :idClass')
             ->andWhere('cc.idComputador = :idComputador')
             ->setParameter('idClass', 15)
             ->setParameter('idComputador', 2510)
             ->getQuery()
             ->getOneOrNullResult();

   if(!$result) {
     throw new \Exception('no results')
   }
```

I would recommend using something like this with doctrine as it is easier to read